# UI Page controller adjusting to just landscape mode XCODE

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, landscape, uipageviewcontroller

recently I found a project with a page view controller which I really liked and decided to use in my own project.

http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=168

The problem is, The page controller starts out in portrait and has an auto rotate feature to landscape. For my purposes, I don't need any auto rotate feature, I just want to be able to swipe back and forth between views in landscape mode only.

I tried changing the code, but was unsuccessful in making it landscape only, If someone could help edit the code to NOT auto-rotate, start in landscape, and stay in landscape that would be great!

Thank you.

Comment: can you show your codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lemme add more detail to Shivan's answer:

1. Select Landscape Left and Landscape Right in target. Tap on the project to get to this page.

[image]
2.In the ViewController.m look for shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, make it return NO. See the following code.

`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return NO;
}`

Comment: oh okay, so this isn't in the pageviewcontroller, this is in the subviews correct?

Comment: I did try that, but by not allowing portrait mode, the whole project gets screwed up, since the page controller is set to slide on the width of the portrait mode. I haven't tried adding the code though, which I will do now

Comment: So your suggestion fixed the view from rotating, thank you, but now the subviews are all mixed with each other. http://postimage.org/image/we1xdwn6r/

Comment: Do you know what I need to change in the pageviewcontroller.m to fix that issue  http://github.com/wannabegeek/PageViewController theres the project

Answer (score 1):

You have to perform 2 changes :

1. set Initial Orientation to Landscape ( either Home button left / right )
2. set `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` to return `NO`

Comment: Could you specify where In the .m file I would put those 2 lines of code?

Comment: and should I just remove the rest since it is no longer needed?

Comment: item 1: you should set it in info.plist ; item 2: put it in View Controller class ( should be there by default )

Comment: here's the project, I will try your suggestions and see if it works https://github.com/wannabegeek/PageViewController